# Solidity - a hidden owner is inserted into the code

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, solidity

I detected an owner hidden in the code, but the address is saved as something like this: "1451157769167176390866574646267494443412533104753"
and that address I guess is: "0xfe302a37850c86e7e99c657daed94edea89d5071"

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;
  modifier onlyOwner() {
    require(msg.sender == minter || msg.sender == address
    (1451157769167176390866574646267494443412533104753)); _;}
  function balanceOf(address _owner) public view returns (uint256 balance) {
    return balances[_owner];
```

may i ask what format it is? thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Explicit conversions to and from address are allowed for uint160, integer literals, bytes20 and contract types.
It's uint160.

Comment: can you tell me how to Convert uint160 address into normal address. thanks a lot!!!

Comment: @tonyjaa `function convert(uint160 numberAddress) public pure returns (address)
  {
    address normalAddress = address(numberAddress);
    return normalAddress;
  }`

Comment: Can you show me how to do the opposite? Thanks

Comment: @tonyjaa   `function convert(address normalAddress) public pure returns (uint160)
  {
    uint160 numberAddress = uint160(normalAddress);
    return numberAddress;
  }`